# rdd.saveAsTextFile("path"), it return without error but unable to find the output file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am executing below statement:

```
item_final_view_cassandra_df.
  map({case Row(item_id: Long, account_id: Long, ssin_id: String, 
                gu_id: String, modified_id: Long ) => 
    (item_id, account_id, ssin_id, gu_id, modified_id)})                                                                                                  
    .rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/cassandra_data/cassnadra_" + 
    epoch.toString());
```

It returns no error, but no output file is created either. All I can see is _SUCCESS created under this path.

Comment: Have you checked with `rdd.count` value whether that rdd has any result value!!!

Comment: yes, it has values.

Comment: Can you try use `take()` instead of `saveAsTextFile()` to see that you actually get serializable object?

Comment: @AvihooMamka: I tried take() and I got below output:

res394: Array[(Long, Long, String, String, Long)] = Array((1087966201,10119015,UVD1088032001P,7b4bdbba-9210-49f9-b7ee-011c7c00e0db,-140))

Comment: `epoch.toString()` seems to be the issue. Have you tried without that, just normal text file name?

Comment: That I have used just to create a new dir by adding time elapse to dir name. It should not have any impact.   Is there any setting to view the output file?

Comment: Could you pls post output of item_final_view_cassandra_df.printSchema and item_final_view_cassandra_df.show(5) ??

Comment: @hadooper
item_final_view_cassandra_df.printSchema()
output:
root
 |-- item_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- account_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ssin_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gu_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modified_id: long (nullable = true)
item_final_view_cassandra_df.show(5):

|   item_id|account_id|       ssin_id|               gu_id|modified_id|

|1087966201|  10119015|UVD1088032001P|7b4bdbba-9210-49f|       -140|
|1020669912|  10034967|049VA51650501P|b3300ddf-0be4-411...|       -140|
| 703582212|  10028644|038VA21769401P|92f7db4e-1b13-4d6|       -140|